# IndexedDB Storage Scope

Tags: indexeddb, web-storage

I have few questions about IndexedDB Storage Scope:

- Does a PWA on Web  Browser (Chrome / Mozilla) will use the same
  instance of IndexedDB as that of PWA added to the screen?
- Will the data persist in Indexed DB before & after adding to the Home Screen?
- If IndexedDB is browser specific, how to persist the data across the
  app opened in multiple browsers which are using the same IndexedDB?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, both the PWA and the browser have access to the same data as part of the same-origin policy ([example with localstorage](https://notepad.js.org/) - tested it by creating indexeddb)
- Yes, the data is shared between app and browser - because PWAs run in the browser
- You would need a server side solution for synchronizing data between browsers